# Splitting ggplot ribbon or line by colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a ribbon along which I highlight certain region of interest by a grouping factor, e.g., using a different colour or alpha.

Here is some made-up data:

```
myYears=1980:2009
randDF <- data.frame(Year=myYears,
                     lowerQ=rnorm(myYears),
                     upperQ=2+rnorm(myYears),
                     mygroup=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(1,10)))
```

first option - split the ribbon by different colours - doesnt work

```
ggplot(randDF)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year,ymin=lowerQ,ymax=upperQ,fill=mygroup))
```

second option - draw the edges of the ribbon in different colours - this draws something but its not right (see graph below)

```
ggplot(randDF)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year,ymin=lowerQ,ymax=upperQ),fill="grey")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=upperQ,colour=factor(mygroup)))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=lowerQ,colour=factor(mygroup)))
```

[image: Click here to see above ggplot]

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to create three groups and colour the line of group 1 and 3 in the same colour:

```
myYears=1980:2009
randDF <- data.frame(Year=myYears,
                     lowerQ=rnorm(myYears),
                     upperQ=2+rnorm(myYears),
                     mygroup=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10)))

ggplot(randDF)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year,ymin=lowerQ,ymax=upperQ,fill=mygroup))

ggplot(randDF)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year,ymin=lowerQ,ymax=upperQ),fill="grey")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=upperQ,colour=factor(mygroup)), size = 2)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=lowerQ,colour=factor(mygroup)), size = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkgreen", "darkred"))
```

There is still a slight issue with the gaps between the groups - workaround might be to duplicate the last value of each group.